# redis Query results order

Tags: redis

I have some doubts in the rightness of my judgment about the order of return results for redis Query, especially for the hgetall one

for example, I put some ammount of data to the database in the order of its enumeration:

```
"key:1" {...} 
"key:3" {...}
"key:10" {...}
"key:2" {...}
```

Will the "KEYS key:*" command without any other params always return this data in the order of its appearance in the database, or will it try to sort the data in any way?

Has anybody seen some official redis article about the topic?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use the `KEYS` statement in production, if you need your solution to be scalable ('N' keys, where N can grow).

Consider using `SCAN`, or similar.

You mention `HGETALL`, this can be valid in some scenarios, but has a Big-O of O(N). If you can't predict how many members there are in the hash set, and/or it's a large number of members, use `HSCAN` instead.

About the order: there is no guarantee whatsoever. It's a dictionary which uses hashes. This applies to `KEYS` and `SCAN` equally. First get all of them, then apply ordering client-side.

If you need server-side sorting, Redis provides two or three mechanisms:

1. Use a Sorted Set. In general: this is quick.
2. Use the `SORT` function. In general: this is slow.
3. Use Lua server-side scripting, with a combination of 1 and/or 2

Hope this helps, TW